# Displaying or hiding an element affects the position of the lower divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the example below, the click on the "Click me" div toggles the display of the "info" div.

Displaying or hiding the "info" div moves down/up the lower divs (3 and 4 in my example).

Is it possible to move the upper divs (1 and 2) instead and keep the lower divs in their position?

```js
function clickMe() {
  var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
  if (infoDiv.style.display === "none") {
    infoDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    infoDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#info {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.lower {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">1</div>
<div class="upper">2</div>
<div onclick="clickMe()">Click me</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div class="lower">3</div>
<div class="lower">4</div>
```

Comment: No. You can get that effect by moving everything though. but only moving the upper two will automatically move the lower two as well. So if you add the same height of the info in front of the first upper, everything will move down the height of the info, giving the visual of the upper two moving.

Comment: don't toggle `display` - toggle `visibility`.

Comment: You could change the opacity or visibility, rather than display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling the visibility or opacity does not actually give the effect that the upper two rows are moving instead of the lower two
And it leaves an ugly white line where the info used to be.

So we fake that effect by adding empty space equal to the info height in front of the rows, so we can 'push' the upper rows up by changing the height of that gutter row.

Same can be done with margin-top and other CSS ways, but this was the easiest one to explain. :)

```js
function clickMe() {
  var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
  var spacer = document.getElementById("spacer");
  if (infoDiv.style.display === "block") {
    infoDiv.style.display = "none";
    spacer.style.height = "16px";
  } else {
    infoDiv.style.display = "block";
    spacer.style.height = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
.upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#info {
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 16px;
  display: none;
}
#spacer {
  height: 16px;
}
.lower {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div class="upper">1</div>
<div class="upper">2</div>
<div onclick="clickMe()">Click me</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div class="lower">3</div>
<div class="lower">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the visibility instead of the display, as [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991950/displaying-or-hiding-an-element-affects-the-position-of-the-lower-divs/56992064#comment100518459_56991950) pointed out:

```js
function clickMe() {
  var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
  if (infoDiv.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    infoDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    infoDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
.upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#info {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.lower {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">1</div>
<div class="upper">2</div>
<div onclick="clickMe()">Click me</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div class="lower">3</div>
<div class="lower">4</div>
```

You can also change the opacity too:

```js
function clickMe() {
  var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
  if (infoDiv.style.opacity === "0") {
    infoDiv.style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    infoDiv.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
```

```css
.upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#info {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.lower {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">1</div>
<div class="upper">2</div>
<div onclick="clickMe()">Click me</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div class="lower">3</div>
<div class="lower">4</div>
```

A cleaner way to write your function would be to use an anonymous function, destructuring and a ternary statement:

```js
const clickMe = ({ style:s }) => s.visibility = s.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden"
```

```css
.upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#info {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.lower {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">1</div>
<div class="upper">2</div>
<div onclick="clickMe(document.getElementById('info'))">Click me</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div class="lower">3</div>
<div class="lower">4</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but what I really need is to keep the lower divs in place and moving the upper divs without leaving any blank space

Answer (score 1):

Don't toggle `display` - toggle `visibility`.

> The visibility CSS property shows or hides an element without changing the layout of a document.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

```js
function clickMe() {
  var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
  if (infoDiv.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    infoDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    infoDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
.upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#info {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.lower {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">1</div>
<div class="upper">2</div>
<div onclick="clickMe()">Click me</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div class="lower">3</div>
<div class="lower">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I you really want to move items up instead of switching visibility only, you need to wrap your content with container. And stick all items to the bottom using flex. But container must have fixed height:

```js
function clickMe() {
  var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
  if (infoDiv.style.display === "none") {
    infoDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    infoDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#info {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.lower {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="upper">1</div>
    <div class="upper">2</div>
    <div onclick="clickMe()">Click me</div>
    <div id="info">info</div>
    <div class="lower">3</div>
    <div class="lower">4</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the idea is very nice for a fixed height, but unfortunately my container must have a responsive height related to its parent